# Boltzmann constant times absolute temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, elasticity

I came across a research paper with the following paragraph in a research paper.

[Research Paper section](https://ibb.co/gVDoH7)

I am trying to fetch fluctuations from Kirchhoff's matrix and that is why I am interested in the (1) formulae.

The question I wish to ask is: In the formulae, Boltzmann's coefficient is multiplied with absolute zero temperature (according to the paragraph followed). However, absolute temperature is always zero (Kelvin scale). How will this fetch any other value than zero?

I got to know there is the combined value of kT. However, I couldn't find any source stating that it is not zero at absolute temperature.

Comment: Be careful when posting screenshots of publications. You might violate copyright terms. It is better to cite the source and quote. In your case, it should be ok but keep it in mind next time... Apart from that, always provide the source.

Answer (score 1):

It just says "absolute" temperature which does not mean "absolute zero". [Absolute temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_temperature) simply refers to the Kelvin scale. Absolute zero would be T = 0K.

Comment: Can you please explain the difference? I googled "absolute temperature" and it says 0 on Kelvin scale.

Comment: I am entirely sure that it did not say the absolute temperature equals 0K. Absolute zero is 0K and absolute temperature refers to a temperature scale. Follow the link that I provided in my answer (click "Absolute temperature" in the answer above). In the first paragraph you will find: "Thermodynamic temperature is often also called absolute temperature, for two reasons: one, proposed by Kelvin, that it does not depend on the properties of a particular material; two that it refers to an absolute zero according to the properties of the ideal gas" [wiki] Where did it say something else?